# CSS - Calculate table column widths

Tags: css, html-table, width, calculated-columns

I have a weird result. I have table like this

```
<table style='width: 100%;'>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th style='width:21px'>col1</th>
            <th>col2</th>
            <th style='width:160px'>col3</th>
            <th style='width:120px'>col4</th>
            <th style='width:130px'>col5</th>
            <th style='width:130px'>col6</th>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

but when I do the following JS :

```
$('table tbody tr:first td').each(function(){
    var int_width = $(this).width();
    alert(int_width);
});
```

It says I have 426px on the 2nd column. Now, when I measure the with with Firefox MeasureIt plugin, I have 433px? Any ideas ?

Comment: your first `tr` only contains `th` - not `td`, have you taken into account any extra cell padding / spacing that gets added

Comment: @Pete and there is not even a `thead` ... Anyway, Toch, do you have any other CSS attazched to this table ?

Comment: it is adding cell-spacing and/or cellpadding. Address this via CSS.

Comment: I mean td instead of th (wrong paste), I have a thead but I didnt write it, a CSS too, but I wanted to write less